# How to find first occurrence with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Using .NET LINQ, I'd like to find entries (Name) that start with PID equal to 0 or 1.  But if the Name has both, I only want 0.  In the following:

```
PID Name
 0  P1
 1  P1
 1  P3
 0  P4
 0  P5
 1  P5
```

I'll get back rows:

```
 0 P1
 1 P3
 0 P4
 0 P5
```

The PID values can go up to 10.  Any suggestions how this can be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use:

```
var results = collection
               .Where(item => item.PID == 0 || item.PID == 1)
               .GroupBy(item => item.Name)
               .Select(g => g.OrderBy(item => item.PID).First());
```

Comment: In group list certainly a member is exist, So Firs() is much readable.

Comment: @4thSpace FirstOrDefault will return a single element.  The GroupBy causes it to group by specific elements, so you return the first element of each group.  You could use FirstOrDefault instead of First above, but the group already does a filtering, so the default will never happen...

Comment: @Reed Copsey I think you need to group by item.Name, but otherwise this looks like the answer.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of statement add ".FirstOrDefault()"

Comment: Does the equal part just need to be 'where PID == 0 || PID == 1'?